# How to label each bar in geom_col() with the value of the y-axis, while keeping the fill mapped to a categorical variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

this is the graph in question:[Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBW7A.png)

I simply need to label each bar with it's respective sleep_total value, but I'm unsure how to get rid of the value for each tiny sliver of the mapping. I just want one value on top of each bar that's the sum of all those slivers AND I want to keep the fill mapping.

My code so far is:

```
    msleep %>% 
  ggplot(aes(order, sleep_total, fill = genus))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = sleep_total), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size =3)+
  theme_minimal()
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: There are a couple of different ways to do this, but to demonstrate it, we would really need some reproducible data. If you could edit your question to include  the output of `dput(antenna)`, I'm sure you would get an answer pretty quickly.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to demonstrate it using one of the many built-in datasets in R? All it would have to have is 2 categorical variables, one for the x axis, one for the mapping, and then a numerical variable to count? I think the msleep dataset would work as a fine proxy, no?

Comment: Yes Nate, that would be perfect,  but the onus is really on the OP to make a reproducible example with a built-in dataset. There is a wide range of prior knowledge and skills amongst folks who ask questions here, and often if we give an answer using a reproducible example that we make ourselves from a built-in data set, the original posters will struggle to apply that to their own data. If you create your own example with a built-in dataset that is much less of a problem. Plus, you are asking people to put in extra effort to solve your problem, when you could have put this effort in yourself.

Comment: fair point! I have now restructured my question to be using a graph and code pertaining to the msleep dataset that mimics the problem I was having :)

Comment: Thank you Nate. Hopefully my answer will allow you to apply this to your real data now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat_summary` with `geom = "text"` and `fun = sum` to generate centered labels that ignore the fill groups:

```r
  msleep %>% 
  ggplot(aes(order, sleep_total))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = genus))+
  stat_summary(fun = sum, geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(y)),
               position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again, Allan! Thank you for a solution--unfortunately though I'm running into another small issue. When I simply just copy your msleep graph code into my Rstudio  I'm getting a "discrete value supplied to continuous scale" error. Would you know why that would be?